# Expressing variance of sum

Tags: random-variables, independence, variance

Let X and Y be two independent random variables with finite variances. If 
, ,  are constants is there a way to simplify ar( + Y + ) in terms of ar() and ar(Y)

Answer (score 1):

For a scalar random varible $z$ that has $\mathbb{E}(z) = \bar{z}$, where $\mathbb{E}$ means the expectation (mean), by definition of the variance,

$Var(z) = \mathbb{E}[(z - \bar{z})^2] = \mathbb{E}[z^2 - 2z\bar{z} + \bar{z}^2] = \mathbb{E}[z^2] - \bar{z}^2$

since the expectation is a linear operator.

Now, plug in $z = aX + bY + c$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
Var(aX+bY+c) &= \mathbb{E}[(aX+bY+c)^2] - (a\overline{X} + b\overline{Y} + c)^2 \\
&= \mathbb{E}[a^2X^2 + b^2Y^2 + c^2 + 2abXY + 2aXc + 2bYc] \\
&\qquad - a^2\overline{X}^2-b^2\overline{Y}^2-c^2-2ab\overline{X}\overline{Y}-2a\overline{X}c-2b\overline{Y}c \\
&= a^2(\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\overline{X}^2) + b^2(\mathbb{E}[Y^2] - \overline{Y}^2)\\
&= a^2Var(X) + b^2Var(Y)
\end{aligned}
$$

Note that the second equality to the third equality is using the independence of $X$ and $Y$ to cancel terms, namely, $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[X]\cdot\mathbb{E}[Y]$.

Comment: Since X and Y are random variables can I say that Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) ? Also does this expand to constants too ? Like Var(aX) = a  * Var(X)

Comment: $Var(X+Y)$ is a special case where $a=b=1$ and $c = 0$ from the above answer, so $Var(X+Y) = 1^2\cdot Var(X) + 1^2\cdot Var(Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y)$. So, yes, you are right about the first. However, $Var(aX) = a^2 Var(X)$ according to the above derivation.